# javascript program returns a number instead of the desired array

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have a program that's supposed to remove items from a list of arguments

```
function destroyer(arr) {
  var args = [].slice.call(arr);
  var data = args.shift();
  for(var i = 0; i < args.length; i++){
    var j = 0;
    while(j < data.length){
      if(args[i] == data[j]){
        data.splice(j,1);
        j = 0;
      }
      else{
        j += 1;
      }
    }
  }
  return data;
}
```

destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3) is supposed to return [1,1] but I'm only getting a response of 1, and I'm not sure why because when I perform the instruction outside the loop, I get the array.

Update: Should look like this.

```
function destroyer(arr) {
  var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
  var data = args[0];
  args.shift();
  for(var i = 0; i < args.length; i++){
    var j = 0;
    while(j < data.length){
      if(args[i] == data[j]){
        data.splice(j,1);
        j = 0;
      }
      else{
        j += 1;
      }
    }
  }
  // Remove all the values
  return data;
}
```

Comment: It's returning 1 because
`destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],2 ,3)` sets `args` to be `[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]`, then you set data to be `args.shift()` which shifts `args` to be `[2, 3, 1, 2, 3]` but sets `data` to be `1`

Comment: [Array.prototype.shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift?v=control) returns the removed element.

Comment: perhaps you meant `var args = [].slice.call(arguments);` - as your code stands, arguments 2 and 3 are never referenced (using es6, you could also change the function definition to `function destroyer(...arr) {` to get the result you expect

Comment: Thanks Jaromanda X!

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) to get the array of elements to remove and [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?v=control) to filter out these elements, like so

```
function destroyer(arr, ...args) {
  return arr.filter(e => !args.includes(e));
}

console.log(destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3)); // [1, 1]
```

Comment: Thanks! I wanted to use filter, but the IDE I'm working in wasn't considering arr.filter a function for some reason

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) to indicate that there will be more parameters

```js
function destroyer(...arr) {
  var args = [].slice.call(arr);
  var data = args.shift();
  for(var i = 0; i < args.length; i++){
    var j = 0;
    while(j < data.length){
      if(args[i] == data[j]){
        data.splice(j,1);
        j = 0;
      }
      else{
        j += 1;
      }
    }
  }
  return data;
}

console.log(destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

## Yet another variant.

```js
function destroyer(array) {
  var pos, args = [].slice.call(arguments, 1),
  arrLength = array.length,
  newArray = [];
  
  while ((arrLength -= 1) >= 0) {
    pos = args.lastIndexOf(array[arrLength]);
    if (!~pos) {
      newArray.unshift(array[arrLength]);
    }
  }

  return newArray;
};

console.log(destroyer([1,2,3,1,2,3], 2, 3));
console.log(destroyer([1,2,3,1,2,3], 1, 3));
console.log(destroyer([1,2,3,1,2,3], 1, 2));
console.log(destroyer([1,2,3,1,2,3], 1, 2, 3));
console.log(destroyer([1,2,3,1,2,3], 4));
```